# Devise account and users strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to figure out how to make a signup process ala basecamphq or as many other SASS apps.

What I would like to do is when someone sign up they create an Account with info like this:
First name
Last name
Company
Subdomain
email
password

And then the account owner can create users that belong to that account.

```
# user 
belongs_to :account

# account 
has_many :users
belongs_to :subscription_plan

# subscription_plan
has_many :accounts
```

Both the account owner and users needs to able to login using the same form.

What is the best strategy to accomplish the above?

## EDIT

Is this the "wright" way to do it or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow [An example Rails 3 app with basecamp like subdomains and authentication (using Devise)](https://github.com/salex/rails3-subdomain-devise). This is a right way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want users and account owner to login from the same form you should somehow check that logged in person belongs to **accounts** or **users** and then render proper page.
Maybe you should create checkbox on login form, for example: "Single user" or something else to verify person's accessory.
Or you can check in **Accounts** table for logged in user by email and if it exists - render proper page. (I chosen **Accounts** because it should be much smaller then **Users** table :) )